# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 can't see my partitioned HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, ubiquity

My computer is running on Windows 10 and I want to dual boot it with Ubuntu 18.04.

Disk Sizes are:

```
C: 148GB  
D: 399GB  
E: 199GB  
F: 155GB  
I: 349MB(System Reserved)
```

I have freed up 25GB unallocated space from F: drive (which was 180GB). I have MBR partitions and not GPT. Previously my disc was dynamic then I learnt that Ubuntu needs basic disk to be installed. Hence it showed: [image: Ubuntu installer not showing free unallocated space when I had dynamic disk]

I converted my dynamic disks to basic disk using AOMEI Dynamic Disk Manager Pro. Here is what my Windows disk management shows:

[image: Disk Manager]

but now I see this green box line that says these 4 partition are now "Extended Partition".

I went ahead to install Ubuntu, but all I see in the installer is:

[image: Ubuntu installer not showing my HDD partitions]

From the Ubuntu installer, I have run some commands from the terminal, those are:
[image: lsblk]

[image: sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda]

[image: sudo fixparts /dev/sda]

[image: sudo LC_MESSAGES=POSIX sfdisk -d /dev/sda]

Also I have run GParted and it shows:

[image: Gparted]

Please help me regarding this so that I can install Ubuntu in the free space which I had allocated for it, I am stuck in it for a long time.

Edit: After executing the commands given by David Foerster, I decided to run the Ubuntu installer again and the option "Install alongside Windows 10" was also available, but I chose to install Ubuntu in the free space which I created for it by going to the "Something Else" option.[image: Install alongside Windows 10]
[image: freespace]

Comment: You should not have made conversion from GPT to MBR. i guess your system is Booting in the mode "UEFI". Are you able to Boot to Windows at this time? Can you confirm booting mode first to proceed further?

Comment: No my computer has MBR and is running on UEFI mode

Comment: windows 10 cant be run on MBR if the boot mode is in UEFI. are you able to boot to windows in UEFI mode? can you send the pic like this https://we.tl/HtAe4qiPmI (in windows diskmgmt.msc, select disk0, properties, Volumes tab)

Comment: Sorry for the mistake in the previous comment, I meant to say: "No my computer has MBR and is running on BIOS mode". There is no volumes tab when I click on properties on the drives except for the unallocated 25 GB free space. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLU28.png

Comment: thats good. you confirmed MBR and BIOS. in windows diskmgmt.msc Click on Disk 0, Right Click, Properties, select Volumes TAB.

Comment: how do I know which is disk 0? For me, it is labelled as Entertainment (E:), Gaming (D:), System (C:) and Stuffs (F:).

Comment: those are all partitions..E,D,C the pic i sent you..observe in the bottom left.. you will see Disk 0 this is the Complete Hard Drive not Partition.

Comment: problem could be.. Your extended partition contains 3 Ntfs partitions and fourth one you allocated for Ubuntu. Try to make one extended partition as Ext4 by moving all your files to other partition.

Comment: PRATAP, here it is: https://we.tl/N94xjEUTJC

Comment: @Apurba Hi, you have to add "@" symbol before the user id's so that user will get notification in their inbox. i have seen the attachment. All conflicts came because you have made running windows partitions from GPT to MBR. as per David Foerster said, you can wait for his reply to sort out this. your data is important here. i recommend you to take backup. after taking backup, try deleting the "848MB Unallocated BlackHighlighted" "847MB Free Space Green Highlighted" then try installing Ubuntu if it shows all the partitions in "Something Else" option with in ubuntu.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Please suggest me some ways to fix this. Here is what AOMEI Partition Assistant shows: https://we.tl/W2WsPmHA8S

I read somewhere that MBR needs 4 primary partitions or 3 primary and 1 logical partition. So according to AOMEI, I have System Reserved(I:) , System (C:) and Entertainment (E:) as primary partitions and Gaming (D:) and Stuffs (F:) as logical partitions. I am confused.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have edited my question and provided terminal outputs as text files rather than image. Waiting for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your partition table is invalid: primary partition #3 lies within the range of primary partition #4, which isn't too bad because #4 is an extended partition meant to contain logical partitions and #3 doesn't overlap with any of those logical partition, but it's still invalid and a careful partition manager will fail and do nothing instead of making things worse.

You can use `fixparts` to fix this issue (according to its manual page):

1. Back up the current Master Boot Record (including the partition table) in case something goes wrong:

   ```sh
   sudo dd if=/dev/sda count=1 > /path/to/sda.mbr
   ```

   The path of the back-up file `/path/to/sda.mbr` should lie on a persistent storage device, e. g. a connected USB drive, as opposed to the ephemeral file system of a live system.

   - If something *does* go wrong and *after you verified that `/dev/sda` still refers to desired drive (which may change on every boot)* you can restore it with the following command:

     ```sh
     sudo dd if=/path/to/sda.mbr of=/dev/sda count=1
     sudo partprobe /dev/sda
     ```
2. Run `fixparts` with the “**l**ogical” (on partition **3**), “**s**ort” and “**w**rite” (confirmed with **y**es) commands:

   ```sh
   printf '%s\n' l 3 s w y | sudo fixparts /dev/sda
   ```

Comment: Yes! after executing all the above commands, I decided to run the Ubuntu installer and it finally showed the unallocated 25 GB free space where I successfully installed Ubuntu. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Apurba. It's nice to hear that you have succeeded. I would like to know what did you put here "path/to/sda.sfdisk" in  `sudo sfdisk - d /dev/sda > /path/to/sda.sfdisk` and how much time it took to take backup after giving this command. Thank you.

Comment: @David Forester you mentioned /path/to/sda.sfdisk do we need to edit /path/to/sda or is it a part of command?

Comment: @PRATAP: I clarified the relevant section of my answer. It really needed that improvement. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @DavidFoerster
`sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > /path/to/sda.sfdisk`
Didn't work for me, so I tried `sfdisk -d /dev/sda > sda.partition.table.08-06-2018.txt` and it worked.
@PRATAP it didn't take any time, as soon as I executed the command, a text file named sda.partition.table.08-06-2018.txt was created in Home

Comment: I have edited my question with the results. Thank you @DavidFoerster and PRATAP