# Not getting "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager"?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10

I'm following this tutorial: [How to Install Ubuntu 18.04 along with Windows 10](https://vitux.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-along-with-windows-10/) .

In the `Installation Type` stage - Windows 10 get identified as I get this message:

> This computer currently has windows 10 on it what would you like to do?

[image]

But I'm not seeing "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows boot manager". Why is it so?

Comment: did you boot in same mode as Windows 10 installation mode? BIOS/UEFI

Comment: Yes both in legacy mode.

Comment: 4 primary partitions limit?

Comment: @krishna is it possible for you to share the pic "This computer currently has windows 10 on it what would you like to do?" yes mikewhatever is in the rite point..

Comment: I've added the image.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1044346/739431

Comment: Probably a good chance that windows has the whole disk space.  Would need to see if you have free/empty space to make new partition.  Should use windows tools to shrink windows if needed.  Will want at least 20GBs for Ubuntu, but more is nicer.

Comment: @crip659 yes you're right. My partitioning was MBR hence it only allowed 4 primary partitions limit. Now I'm transferring to GPT after backing up all the data.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way setting up a multi boot system is making the partitioning by yourself with a partition tool of you choice first (GParted works fine) and then installing your preferred OS. Especially when you want to set up multiple OS the option "install  alongside " of the standard installer is often not that helpful - because it often simply doesn't do what it should do.

So my recommodation:

1. Make the partioning - 2 primary partitions. (A nice side effect of doing the partitioning by yourself is that you are able to configure the size of them easily)
2. Install Windows on the first partition
3. Install Linux/Ubuntu on the second one - to do so choose "something else"
   choose the second partition as root mountpoint (the "/" in the menu) and the first partition or the whole drive (where you installed windows first) as the bootloader installation. Optional: Configure some SWAP Memory. (Mostly Available RAM divided by 2)

This works fine for me.

Comment: Works good for setting up a new drive, but OP already has windows installed, probably with data on it.